# Performing SQL string manipulations on a single column

Tags: mysql, string, interview-question

I recently came across a problem at an interview which I wasn't able to answer. The ask was to write some SQL fetch the first three number(s) after crossing two 2 decimals.

For example:
Input table:

```
IP address
1.2.3.4.5
11.22.33.44.55
5.6.7.8.9
111.222.333.444
.
.
.
```

```
Output table:
IP address
1.2.3
11.22.33
5.6.7
111.222.333
.
.
```

My initial approach was to use the inbuilt substring. For example: select substring(ip,0,5) from table. But this is a broken logic as it does not account for values such as 11.22.33 or 111.222.333

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`IP_address` varchar(15))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`IP_address`)
> VALUES
>     ('1.2.3.4.5'),
>     ('11.22.33.44.55'),
>     ('5.6.7.8.9'),
>     ('111.222.333.444')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`IP_address`,'.',3) FROM Table1;
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUBSTRING_INDEX(`IP_address`,'.',3) |
> | :---------------------------------- |
> | 1.2.3                               |
> | 11.22.33                            |
> | 5.6.7                               |
> | 111.222.333                         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de08bcfcd5cdb6e1639dc61b718e62c0)*